# How to achieve functionality of headless service + port translation of the FQDNs that are created by that headless service in kuberentes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

What's the best way to create a functionality of headless service + port translation of the FQDNs that are created by that headless service?
I have created this headless service where the selector is a stateful set with replica=3. Basically creating the headless service to get the FQDN functionality. But I also want the port translation for these FQDNS. For example, when some internal microservice uses :443 it should be routed to :7443 on the pod. What's the best way to achieve that?

```
Name:              sbijendra-service
Namespace:         avictrl-aviproject-aviclusterinstaller-system
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/instance=sbijendra
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=sbijendra-sts,app.kubernetes.io/kind=sbijendra-statefulset,app.kubernetes.io/name=sbijendra
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                None
IPs:               None
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        7443/TCP
Endpoints:         100.109.187.135:7443,100.111.94.144:7443,100.127.8.17:7443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I added the port and target port in the headless service itself but looks like it is not going to work.

Comment: I can't help, but I'd like to check one thing. The headless Service ignores the `Port` part of the definition, and just uses the actual ports on which the application on pod has exposed its functionality?